# Programmatically find out what fieldset a field belongs to, if any

Tags: entities

There doesn't seem to be a way to join the fieldset table in the database to a fields table, nor any function that can be used to get fieldset info by field name. Is there a way to get fieldset info starting from a single field's information (as well as bundle and such)?

Answer (score 1):

If you call `field_group_info_groups` with the entity type and bundle, it will return all the field groups on the bundle, the fields should be in the children array under `['form'][YOUR_FIELDGROUP]` e.g.

```
     $fieldgroups = field_group_info_groups('node', "YOUR_NODETYPE");
     $field_names = $fieldgroups['form']['YOUR_FIELDGROUP']->children;
```

`$fieldnames` should now contain a list of all the fields that pertain to `YOUR_FIELDGROUP`. Which you can now parse through using a foreach loop.

```
     $node = node_load(2);
     foreach ($field_names as $key => $field_name) {
      $field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, $field_name);
      // Do something cool here. 
     }
```

Comment: Here's the docs page for this... http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/field_group/field_group.module/function/field_group_info_groups/7